# How do I pass HTML5 Geolocation API coordinates to my Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openweathermap

I'm trying to create a simple add using the Open Weather API gem where a user can click a button and the current weather in their location is shown. I would like to use the HTML5 Geolocation API to return the user's current location coordinates and use these to fetch the data from the Open Weather API. How do I pass the `latitude` and `longitude` values from my JS to my controller or service class? At the moment I have this code:

locations.js

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

services/open_weather_api.rb

```
class OpenWeatherApi
  require 'open_weather'

  def initialize(lat, lon, units, appid = "abcdef123456")
    @options = { units: "metric", APPID: appid }
    @lat = lat
    @lon = lon
  end

  def my_location_forecast
    OpenWeather::Current.geocode(@lat, @lon, @options)
  end
end
```

forecast_controller.rb

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController

  def current_weather
    @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new(@lat, @lon, @options).my_location_forecast
  end
end
```

current_weather.html.erb

```
<p>Forecast: <%= @forecast['weather'][0]['description']%></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this be sure to modify according to your needs.

In location.js you can make the ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/locations",
  data: { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude }
  success: function(data){
 }
});
```

And in your controller

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_locations, only: [:current_weather]

 def locations
  @lat = param["data"]["latitude"]
  @lon = params["data"]["longitude"]
  respond_to do |format|
   format.json { success: "success" }
  end
 end

  def current_weather
    @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new(@lat, @lon, @options)
  end
end
```

and in

```
 routes.rb

get "/location", to: "forecasts#locations"
```

Comment: I don't understand how I where to add this JQuery code exactly?

Comment: you can place in your javascript and get latitude and longitude and make ajax request it will be helpful if you push your code into github so that i could exactly notify you where to put this